# An object reference is required to access non-static member, GoogleVR + Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-vr

As soon as I import the GoogleVR for Unity asset into the newest version of Unity, I get the following compile errors:

`` Assets/GoogleVR/Scripts/Controller/Internal/Emulator/EmulatorClientSocket.cs(74,46): error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()' ``

`` Assets/GoogleVR/Scripts/Controller/Internal/Emulator/EmulatorClientSocket.cs(79,17): error CS1061: Type `System.Diagnostics.Process' does not contain a definition for `Close' and no extension method `Close' of type `System.Diagnostics.Process' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ``

This is happening on a totally empty project with the most recent versions of GoogleVR and Unity for OSX. Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: Looks like this is the version of the code?  https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/blob/master/GoogleVR/Scripts/Controller/Internal/Emulator/EmulatorClientSocket.cs#L74

Comment: It looks like your .NET environment is broken, according to the official documentation those calls exist since .NET 1.1.  Are you building for some restricted profile?

* https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.close.aspx

Comment: @BenVoigt Unity does use a restricted profile, you may be right. EDIT: But that package is specifically for unity, so that should not be a problem to use it.

Comment: @BenVoigt Not sure if helpful, I'm on a Mac.

Comment: @bumpkin: You're using .NET so you must have Mono.... I'm not sure whether Unity updates Mono for you or you need to update it separately.

Comment: @BenVoigt Tried downloading and installing new Mono, didn't work :-/

Comment: What platform are your build settings set to? And manually updating Mono is not going to help you.You'll have to use what Unity bundles with, which for now is a fairly outdated version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated Unity to 5.4.0B20 (the most recent Beta version) and it just worked. Found that solution on the Unity forums, but now can't find where.

Answer (score 0):

[This is due to the fact that in some version of Unity, the default platform is WebGL. You can solve this by switching to the Android platform in File | Build Settings.](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/issues/228)

You can switch the platform by File -> Build Setting -> select Android and click Switch Platform